# Why can´t I get this very easy tooltip code work..?

Tags: tooltip

Yes...now I´m bringing the most simple script in the world...and though I can´t get it work!

**MUST** the word, tooltip be included in the .js file to work ? It doesn´t exist in my .js

May I include more .js files in my script, or should I just take the newest release ?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#outdoor img[title]").tooltip();
        });
</script>

<style type="text/css">

#tooltip
{
    display:none;
    font-size:12px;
    height:70px;
    width:160px;
    padding:20px;
    color:Gray;
}
#outdoor #nature
{

   margin-top:200px;

}

</style>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>


<div id="tooltip"></div>

<div id="outdoor">
<img src="../img/forest.jpg" id="nature" alt="ghghg" title="I love the nature"/>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't written a tooltip() function in Javascript, that's why it doesn't work.

You need to include in your HTML file, these lines:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/jquery.tooltip.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/jquery.tooltip.css" />
```